# 2D array plotting in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors

I was trying to plot a 2D array vs a 1D array with pyplot. I can do that with no problems and columns in the 2D array are treated like two different sets of Y datas, which is what i want. What i don't know is how to specify a different color for every column in the 2d array. if i use `pyplot.plot(1darray, 2darray, "r-")` every column in 2d array is plotted red for example. Should i modify the standard color map or is there a smarter way?

Comment: Have you tried leaving out the color specification, and just let matplotlib choose the colors? I mean this: `pyplot.plot(1darray, 2darray, "-")`

Comment: yes, but i want to choose the colors for the different columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use custom colors for each column, then the best approach is to plot each column explicitly using a loop:

```
for column, colcolor in zip(2darray, colors):
    pyplot.plot(2darray, column, "-", color=colcolor)
```

You may have to use `2darray.T`, I'm not sure, and I can't check right now.

Comment: no, normally you should transpose them but the cycle pick up the first element anyway